# Integrals with functions as bounds

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

How to calculate integral such as $$\int_{g(χ)}^{φ(χ)} f(s) \, ds$$ where $F'(s)=f(s)$ Integrals like this appear often  in  PDE's .I'd like to know the whole theory i mean if there is a formula how did you derive to the formula etc.I just treat $φ(χ)$ and $g(χ)$ like they are Constants So i just integrate $f(s)$ and then take the difference $F(φ(χ))-F(g(x))$ is that right? WHy is that true?How to use calculus theorem to derive to such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is continuous and that $\phi$, $g$ are differentiable.

Suppose $$H(x) = \int_0^x f(s) \, ds.$$ The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that $H'(x) = f(x)$.

Suppose that $$M(x) = \int_0^{\phi(x)} f(s) \, ds.$$ Then $M(x) = H(\phi(x))$ so that the chain rule tells you $$M'(x) = H'(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) = f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x).$$

The additivity of the integral tells you finally that
$$ \left( \int_{g(x)}^{\phi(x)} f(s) \, ds \right)'= f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) - f(g(x))g'(x).$$

Comment: Did not know i can interchange  differentiation and integration.

Comment: That's not required here. Just the fundamental theorem and the chain rule.

Comment: but how can i get from your last equation to $$\int_{g(χ)}^{φ(χ)} f'(s) \, ds$$

Comment: nowhere in your question did you ask about the integral of $f'$.

Comment: I said Knowing $F'(s)=f(s)$ which with F'(s) you have used H'(s)